# python 3.6 Tkinter Label attribute error when using .grid

Tags: python, tkinter

I am beginning to get the hang of tkinter, but I have run into a problem. I want to create a label that displays an appropriate message according to the values of an Entry field, checked by a button. When this is used repeatedly, using just the tk.Label command will just overlay on top of the existing label, So I am trying to  assign the label to a variable:

```
messagebox=tk.Label(root2,text="                       ",font(style,font).grid(row=1,column=0,columnspan = 50))
```

I want to later on use the .configure command to change this text, However I get this error:

```
Exception in Tkinter callback
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 1699, in __call__
return self.func(*args)
File "C:[CENSORED BY POSTER (me), It was just the file directory]", line 84, in Checkpass
messagebox = tk.Label(root2,text="                       ",font=(style,font).grid(row=1,column=0,columnspan = 50))
AttributeError: 'tuple' object has no attribute 'grid'
```

Can anyone please tell me what I am doing wrong and explain why it wont work.
Thank you,
Tava

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check your parentheses at `font(style,font).grid`. Probably should be:

```
messagebox=tk.Label(root2,text="                       ",font(style,font)).grid(row=1,column=0,columnspan = 50)
```

But I personally recommend split it into two lines for the sake of readability:

```
messagebox = tk.Label(root2, text="                       ", font(style, font))
messagebox.grid(row=1, column=0, columnspan = 50)
```

Comment: Not only for the sake of readability but also that if not separated like that `messagebox` just returns `None`. Which I doubt what OP would want.

Comment: thanks so much! Also, can someone explain to me why it returns `None`? is it just a tkinter thing or is there an actual reason behind it?

Comment: @Tava Because you create a widget and call `.grid` on the same line. The `grid()` method returns `None` so the reference to the widget isn't stored anywhere. So if you need to store ref to a widget then call widget creation and `grid()` separately, as in my answer and in the Nae's link.